# Change into date format

Tags: r

The column has value like "1010-01-01T12:15:16". It is a string and I want to convert it into time format "1010-01-01 12:15:16".

I tried as.POSIXct() and strptime() but neither works.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(mycolumn, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: I’m sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I also find another way to do it: as.POSIXct(strptime(mycolumn, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lubridate package, which has many convenient functions for working with dates and time. To convert the string to the date/time format you seek:
`lubridate::as_datetime("1010-01-01T12:15:16")`
gives
`"1010-01-01 12:15:16 UTC"`

When the structure is examined `str(lubridate::as_datetime("1010-01-01T12:15:16"))`
shows `POSIXct[1:1], format: "1010-01-01 12:15:16"`